# How to join objects in one query using Parse.com and Unity3D

Tags: c#, object, unity-game-engine, parse-platform, relationship

I am fairly new to Parse and are trying to switch to parse from an php/mysql solution. I am making a multiplayer game with Unity3D in which you can play one on one. My issue concerns the game menu. One game consists of 3 objects. 1 main game object (class:Games) and then 2 player objects (class:GamePlayers). These 2 objects have 2 different references/relations to other objects. 1 to the gameObjectId and one to the playerObjectId (class:Players). I have not used the pointer or relation for this course I am not sure how to use them?

Now, to get all the games a player is involved in I call the GamePlayers class to find all objects in which the current players objectId is.

```
void getGames(string playerObjectId){

    var query = ParseObject.GetQuery("GamePlayers")
        .WhereEqualTo("playerObjectId", playerObjectId);
    query.FindAsync().ContinueWith(t => {

        if (t.IsFaulted){

        } else {

            IEnumerable<ParseObject> results = t.Result;

            foreach (var result in results) {

                getGameData(result.Get<string>("gameObjectId"), playerObjectId, result.Get<string>("playerTiles"), result.Get<int>("playerTurn"));

            }
        }   
    });
}
```

From this I call another method (getGameData) in which I would like to get the game data and opponent game data for each game.

```
void getGameData(string gameObjectId, string playerObjectId, string playertiles, int playerTurn){

    string bagtiles = "";
    string tabletiles = "";
    string newtiles = "";
    int lastdraw = 0;
    int sqlid = 0;

    string oppObjectId = "";
    string oppDataReturn = "";

    var query = ParseObject.GetQuery("Games")
        .WhereEqualTo("objectId", gameObjectId);
    query.FindAsync().ContinueWith(t => {

        if (t.IsFaulted){

        } else {

            IEnumerable<ParseObject> results = t.Result;

            foreach (var result in results) {

                bagtiles = result.Get<string>("bagtiles"); 
                tabletiles = result.Get<string>("tabletiles"); 
                newtiles = result.Get<string>("newtiles"); 
                sqlid = result.Get<int>("sqlId"); 

            }

        }

    });

    query = ParseObject.GetQuery("GamePlayers")
        .WhereEqualTo("gameObjectId", gameObjectId)
            .WhereNotEqualTo("playerObjectId", playerObjectId);
    query.FindAsync().ContinueWith(t => {

        if (t.IsFaulted){

        } else {

            IEnumerable<ParseObject> results = t.Result;

            foreach (var result in results) {

                oppObjectId = result.Get<string>("playerObjectId");
                lastdraw = result.Get<int>("lastDraw");

            }

        }   
    });
}
```

Now, all I am missing is the opponents playerdata e.g. username etc.

```
var query = ParseObject.GetQuery("Players")
    .WhereEqualTo("objectId", oppObjectId);
query.FindAsync().ContinueWith(t => {

    if (t.IsFaulted){

    } else {

        IEnumerable<ParseObject> results = t.Result;

        foreach (var result in results) {

            oppName = result.Get<string>("username");

        }
    }
});
```

I though about running yet another method but it seems like this could be done more effectually and maybe in one query?!?

At the end I add each game to my gamelist like so:

```
if(playerTurn == 0){
    myturn.Add(gameObjectId+"^"+sqlid+"^"+bagtiles+"^"+tabletiles+"^"+newtiles+"^"+playertiles+"^"+lastdraw+"^"+oppObjectId);
} else if(playerTurn == 1){
    theirturn.Add(gameObjectId+"^"+sqlid+"^"+bagtiles+"^"+tabletiles+"^"+newtiles+"^"+playertiles+"^"+lastdraw+"^"+oppObjectId);
} else if(playerTurn > 1){
    finnished.Add(gameObjectId+"^"+sqlid+"^"+bagtiles+"^"+tabletiles+"^"+newtiles+"^"+playertiles+"^"+lastdraw+"^"+oppObjectId);
}
```

Hope this makes sense and somebody can guide me in the right direction. I am not an expert in C# but am learning ;-)

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Before handling specific code challenges, you need to think about your data model. Did you "copy" the data model from your SQL backend when you moved to parse? Moving from a relational db to a NoSQL-backed service like parse requires new thinking. You need to focus on queries rather than relations and normalisation. Reading through the Anypic tutorial on parse.com gives you a good understanding of the different approach when working with NoSQL. I will try and help you more when I am not on my iPhone.

Comment: Ah ok... help would be very appreciated. I am totally new to the NoSQL part :-/

Comment: BTW... I am willing to pay for hours in this matter.

Comment: So if I understand this correct. It's better to have as much data in one object instead of in several of objects?

Comment: No, but I.e. store lists of objects. Sorry I haven't come back to you, but I am on vacation in another country for the weekend, so I am only on my iPhone. Start by writing down the queries your app will do, and what objects those queries should return. Join tables etc from the SQL world are not the way to go.

Comment: As an example, if you have a database with teachers, classes and students, that is a many-to-many relationship. In SQL you would probably model that with several entities between (like Class, Classmember etc). With SQL, you focus on queries. If your most frequent query is "Get list of all students for a teacher", you would put an array of student objects on the teacher class for fast querying, and then maybe code for "eventual consistency".  I will help you more with this later, mate :-)

Comment: Thanks Handsomeguy, I will dig into this and see if I can make sense of this... Enjoy your vacation and I will most certain be back with more questions :-)

Comment: My last comment should have said "With NoSQL, you focus on queries...". Autocorrect... :-)